# Analyze 3D objects by Voxels

Tags: voxel, openvdb

I plan to use OpenVDB to analyze 3D objects/meshes. The objective is:

- To detect object surface regions with a certain criterion, like slope
- Then manipulate those regions
- The manipulation might be adding other 3D objects to those regions, for example

[image: Teapot model]

OpenVDB has some [tools](https://www.openvdb.org/about/) available:

1. Conversion Tools
2. Filters
3. Topological Operations
4. Level Set Tools
5. Morphological Operations
6. Geometric Transforms
7. Compositing Tools
8. ...

It is a large set of confusing tools to choose from. Does anybody with OpenVDB experience know:

1. Is OpenVDB the proper library to achieve my objective
2. If so, which OpenVDB tool best suits my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by OpenVDB community:

> An important question is what you mean by "3D objects/meshes."
>
> OpenVDB is very good at performing those regions with surfaces by
>   representing them as signed distance fields.  But the word "mesh"
>   raises some alarm bells that you may want to maintain topology.  In
>   this case another library may be more effective.
>
> It also sounds like you have a problem domain you are trying to
>   explore.  For that, I would not go straight to code but instead
>   explore solutions using 3d applications first.  My own biased first
>   choice would be Houdini, whose apprentice version you can get for
>   free.  This provides most of the VDB code as separate nodes.  So, for
>   example, you can use a File SOP to load a mesh from disk, a VDB From
>   Polygons to convert it to a Signed Distance FIeld, and then VDB
>   Analysis to compute the Gradient.  The gradient I think matches what
>   you are looking for as slope, but it is also possible you are looking
>   for curvature...
>
> To return to mesh land, you can use a VDB Convert.  Finally a ROP
>   Geometry can save it out.
>
> Attached is a file showing a network to compute an approximate Y-slope
>   as a volume, apply it back to a mesh, and save to disk.

[Attached file](https://lists.aswf.io/g/openvdb-user/attachment/178/0/vdbslope.hip.gz)